# Skip RewriteCond in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I already have defined the following condition in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)$ /browse.php?table=catalog&from=$2
```

Now, in this condition I have to add more. One of them is to skip defined rules if filename is:

```
/products/util/calendar.php
```

Can you help me how to add it in condition defined above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that should do it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/products/util/calendar.php$
```

The Apache documentation is pretty dense, use it: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond